# Password input field displays wrong on safari 9.1

Tags: css, html, safari

Basic input fields of type Password display badly on safari 9.1

The problem is the 'Key' in safari. This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord *" name="password" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Bevestig wachtwoord *" name="password_confirmation" required="">
</div>
```

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Safari**

[image]

Setting `height:100%';` will fix the problem but this obviously changes the height of the field, which is not what i want.

Css:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    -ms-transition: all .35s;
    -o-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

Comment: can you also share the css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the padding from the input object was the solution.

```
input[type="password"] {
    padding: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and searched high and low for a solution which in the end turned out to be as easy as: `line-height: normal`;

This seems to work across browsers for me .. hope you get the same result!

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this didn't solve it for me. The only thing that makes it readable is adjusting the height to something bigger, but that obviously will look ugly because it makes the password fields bigger than the other fields

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).